# Backbone - shared model

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js, model, shared

I started reading some Backbone tutorials and I found one thing that astonishes me. Why models are created inside of view? What if I want two different views for one model (what I think MVC is for)? Let's say I need a model `Colors`, `DisplayView` view which displays them and `ControlsView` which allows me to set their configuration. How to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone does not require that you create your models inside your views - you can (and often should) create your models independently of your views so that they can be shared. Also, just because you create a model inside a view doesn't mean you can't pass a reference to that model to another view and share it that way.

Most likely the tutorials you are reading are very simple and create single models for single views to make the tutorial easier to follow.